# Binomial distribution probability mass function where $p$ depends on index

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Say you have a list of $n$ random integers in the range $[1, m]$. The binomial PMF can find the probability of exactly $k$ occurrences of a number with $p = \frac{1}{m}$
$$ {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$

Now say the list is constructed in the following way: the $i$th element in the list is a random number in $[1, min(i, m)]$, with $n > m$. As a result, $p$ is no longer the same at each index.

$$\text{Instead of }\left[\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m}, ..., \frac{1}{m}\right] \text{it becomes}\left[\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ..., \frac{1}{m - 2}, \frac{1}{m - 1}, \frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m}, ..., \frac{1}{m}\right]$$

How should you solve the same problems of $k$ occurrences of a number? Would it still be correct to use the PMF, with $p$ as the average probability of the desired number at each index (see example below)? Or is there another function to compute this?

Example: $n = 10$ and $m = 6$, what is the probability that 3 occurs exactly 3 times in the list? (Another way to phrase the problem: there are 3 marbles in a bag, only 1 marble is gold. On each turn you pick a marble, place it back, and then add a non-gold marble to the bag. What is the probability of picking the gold marble 3 times in 8 tries?)

The probability of a 3 at each index is

$$\left[\frac{0}{1}, \frac{0}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}\right]$$

Since it's not possible to have a 3 in the first two indices they are ignored, and the value assigned to p is the average of the above

$$p=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{5}{6}\right)$$

to be used with $n=8$ and $k=3$ for the PMF.

Comment: Do you mean $[1, \min(i, m)]$ instead? As in your example you mean the first two indices are not possible to have a $3$ - so that will be $\text{Uniform}[1, 1]$ and $\text{Uniform}[1, 2]$ for the first two indices.

Comment: @BGM That's correct, I had assumed $i$ begins at 0.